# ng-switch according to class

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

I didn't get totally ng-switch. That's what I want to do:
I have my body which has a class that can change according to a button I click.

```
<body class="green">
      ....
<button onclick="document.body.className='green'">green</button>
<button onclick="document.body.className='blue'">blue</button>
```

the think is I need to include a text through ng-include and I want it to be

```
<div ng-include="green.html"></div> //if body has class green
<div ng-include="blue.html"></div> //if body has class blue
```

I know I can do this with ng-switch but I don't know how.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Fabio, non è chiaro cosa vuoi ottenere, spiegati meglio... :-)

Comment: you could do `ng-include="color == 'green' ? 'green.html': 'blue.html'"`

Comment: Have you even tried using it?  You say you are confused about `ng-switch`, but your code doesn't even show `ng-switch` or any of your attempts.  Showing an attempt that doesn't work or has the wrong syntax is better than just saying you don't understand and expecting someone to write a solution for you....

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this:

```
<button ng-click="updateBodyClass('green')">green</button>
<button ng-click="updateBodyClass('blue')">blue</button>

<div ng-switch on="bodyClass">
    <div ng-include="green.html" ng-switch-when="green"></div> //if body has class green
    <div ng-include="blue.html" ng-switch-when="blue"></div> //if body has class blue
</div>


//inside your controller
$scope.updateBodyClass = function(color) {
    document.body.className = color;
    $scope.bodyClass = color;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

a shorter version:

```
<button ng-click="flag='green'">green</button>
<button ng-click="flag='blue'">blue</button>

<div ng-switch on="flag">
    <div ng-include="green.html" ng-switch-when="green"></div> 
    <div ng-include="blue.html" ng-switch-when="blue"></div> 
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this can work

```
<button ng-click="color='green'">green</button>
<button ng-click="color='blue'">blue</button>

<div>
    <div ng-include="green.html" ng-if="color==green"></div> //if body has class green
    <div ng-include="blue.html" ng-if="color==blue"></div> //if body has class blue
</div>
```